# Folium package not installing

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization, folium

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'
```

I tried running conda install - conda-forge folium and tried to install the packages. but then Error is displayed.

Comment: This question is not related to using the Highcharts library.

Comment: yes, i know but i am working on highcharts on EDA part of a classification problem.So it was just i added to know for the community people in stack overflow let know the problem on my objective. if you can be able to help me out of it. guide me on folium package